# How to search for more than 5 Keywords [Pytrend]

Tags: python, keyword

So I am trying to find keyword frequencies in Google Trends.
As the title states, how can I compare more than 5 keywords with Pytrend?
This is the code I use, that works with only 5 keywords:

```
import pandas as pd
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrend = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)
keywords = ["One Piece","Naruto", "Akame Ga Kill","Jujutsu Kaisen","One-Punch Man"]
pytrend.build_payload(
     kw_list=keywords,
     cat=0,
     timeframe = 'today 1-m',
     geo='',
     gprop='')
data = pytrend.interest_over_time()
data = data.cumsum()
data.to_csv('Test.csv', encoding='utf_8_sig')

data = data.drop(labels=['isPartial'],axis='columns')
data.to_csv('Test.csv', encoding='utf_8_sig')
```

I actually want to compare a few hundreds keywords, if anyone knows what the max number of keywords is, would be helpful, too.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try passing your few hundred keywords?
Because I don't really know why there should be a limit..

Comment: @m1ghtfr3e Yes I did - I tried all kind of combinations, and I can verify that the limit is 5

Comment: Ah yes, I was looking at Google Trends and you can not compare more than 5 keywords at the same time. I think you need to do 5 after 5 and so on. And after somehow merge or structure the solutions. 
In fact I am not sure if this works, because I saw in the code of pytrends that there is also some Quota Limit at Google Trends.